Getting error when running "npm run simulate" for js source code using "@chainlink/functions-toolkit"
I've been trying to implement Chainlink Functions Toolkit in my JS code. But, after running this command:
npm run simulate

I get the following error:

secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version
undefined
syntax error, RAM exceeded, or other error
error: Module not found "file:///tmp/FunctionsScript-1715359176579.ts"


Here are the files that I'm using in my code:
swa-func.js
const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@5.7.2');

const abiCoder = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder();

const characterId = args[0];

const url = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${characterId}/`;

const req = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
    url,
})

const res = await req;


if (res.error) {
    console.log(res.error);
    throw Error("Request failed");
}


console.log("res data available")

console.log("response", res.data)

const character = res.data.name;
const height = res.data.height;

console.log(characterId)
console.log(character)
console.log(height)

const encoded = abiCoder.encode([`string`, `string`, `string`], [characterId, character, height]);

return ethers.getBytes(encoded);
// return Functions.encodeString(`${character} ${height}`);

Functions-request-config.js
const fs = require("fs")
// const { Location, ReturnType, CodeLanguage } = require("@chainlink/functions-toolkit")

// Loads environment variables from .env.enc file (if it exists)
require("@chainlink/env-enc").config()

const Location = {
    Inline: 0,
    Remote: 1,
}

const CodeLanguage = {
    JavaScript: 0,
}

const ReturnType = {
    uint: "uint256",
    uint256: "uint256",
    int: "int256",
    int256: "int256",
    string: "string",
    bytes: "Buffer",
    Buffer: "Buffer",
}

// Configure the request by setting the fields below
const requestConfig = {
    // String containing the source code to be executed
    source: fs.readFileSync("./swa-func.js").toString(),
    //source: fs.readFileSync("./API-request-example.js").toString(),
    // Location of source code (only Inline is currently supported)
    codeLocation: Location.Inline,
    // Optional. Secrets can be accessed within the source code with `secrets.varName` (ie: secrets.apiKey). The secrets object can only contain string values.
    secrets: {},
    // Optional if secrets are expected in the sourceLocation of secrets (only Remote or DONHosted is supported)
    //   secretsLocation: Location.DONHosted,
    // Args (string only array) can be accessed within the source code with `args[index]` (ie: args[0]).
    args: ["2"],
    // Code language (only JavaScript is currently supported)
    codeLanguage: CodeLanguage.JavaScript,
    // Expected type of the returned value
    expectedReturnType: ReturnType.bytes,
    // expectedReturnType: ReturnType.string,
    // Redundant URLs which point to encrypted off-chain secrets
    secretsURLs: [],
}

module.exports = requestConfig

Functions-simulate-script.js
const { simulateScript } = require("@chainlink/functions-toolkit");
const requestConfig = require('./Functions-request-config');

async function main() {
    const { responseBytesHexstring, capturedTerminalOutput, errorString } = await simulateScript(requestConfig);

    console.log(responseBytesHexstring);
    console.log(errorString)
    console.log(capturedTerminalOutput);
}

// node Functions-simulate-script.js
main();

package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "simulate": "node ./Functions-simulate-script.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chainlink/env-enc": "^1.0.5",
    "@chainlink/functions-toolkit": "^0.2.8",
    "secp256k1": "^5.0.0"
  }
}

How do I get it to work with chainlink functions toolkit ?
P.S., The API is working fine as it gives the expected output when I run:
node swa-example.js

swa-example.js
const characterId = "2";

async function main() {
    const url = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${characterId}/`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json);
}

main()

Edit: I will like to provide the link to the repo: https://github.com/thoroughProgrammer/chainlink_functions_example_1

In swa-func.js file, the way you're accessing AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder() and getBytes() functions using ethers library. It works like this, in case of ethers v6. So, you can change the import to v6 in the first line as:
const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.12.1');

Also, you can parse the characterId and height values to integer using parseInt(), and use uint256 for them while encoding, so as to make the encoded response fit under 256 bytes.
Here's the revised code:
const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.12.1');

const abiCoder = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder();

const characterId = args[0];

const url = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${characterId}/`;

const req = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
    url,
})

const res = await req;


if (res.error) {
    console.log(res.error);
    throw Error("Request failed");
}


console.log("res data available")

console.log("response", res.data)

const character = res.data.name;
const height = parseInt(res.data.height);

console.log(characterId)
console.log(character)
console.log(height)

const encoded = abiCoder.encode([`uint256`, `string`, `uint256`], [parseInt(characterId), character, height]);

console.log(encoded)

return ethers.getBytes(encoded);


If you want to use ethers v5, then here's the code:
const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@5.7.2');

const abiCoder = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder;

const characterId = args[0];

const url = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${characterId}/`;

const req = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
    url,
})

const res = await req;


if (res.error) {
    console.log(res.error);
    throw Error("Request failed");
}


console.log("res data available")

console.log("response", res.data)

const character = res.data.name;
const height = parseInt(res.data.height);

console.log(characterId)
console.log(character)
console.log(height)

const encoded = abiCoder.encode([`uint256`, `string`, `uint256`], [parseInt(characterId), character, height]);

console.log(encoded)

return ethers.utils.arrayify(encoded);


Edit: After reviewing the contracts from the shared repo.
I've created a PR by doing the following changes:

Changed the FunctionsSource contract to a library having a getStarwarsCharacters() function, and then using the same in the sendRequest() function.

s_lastRequestId was not getting updated  in sendRequest() function, therefore getting reverted n fulfillRequest() with UnexpectedRequestID custom error. So, now it's getting updated with the returned value of _sendRequest() as:
// Send the request and store the request ID
s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(
        req.encodeCBOR(),
        subscriptionId,
        gasLimit,
        donID
);



